# How to prevent IPython from outputting into the console in Colab?

Tags: ipython, google-colaboratory

I'm using Ipython with the `%store` command to store variables. Unfortunally it is printing something like `Stored 'test' (int)`. How can I suppress this?

regards

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!

I personally use the following:

```
from google.colab import output
print('something')
output.clear()
```